# How to combine multiple columns in R

Tags: r, tidy

Suppose I have this data set:

```
     age      height       weight
   "1/2/3"  "12/15/18"   "30/40/37"
```

How can I have a dataset like a dataset below?

```
   age height weight
    1    12     30
    2    15     40
    3    18     37
```

And what if my dataset was like this:

```
  name     age      height       weight
 "Jack"  "1/2/3"  "12/15/18"   "30/40/37"
```

I want to have a data set like below:

```
    name  age height weight
   "Jack"  1    12     30
   "Jack"  2    15     40
   "Jack"  3    18     37
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't mind using external package, you can use `separate_rows()` from the `tidyr` package.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% separate_rows(-name, sep = "/")

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  name  age   height weight
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> 
1 Jack  1     12     30    
2 Jack  2     15     40    
3 Jack  3     18     37
```

Comment: I always use tidyverse. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AllanCameron You're right. I'm so sorry. I made some changes again so your answer is correct, too.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in data frame format like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(age = '1/2/3', height = '12/15/18', weight = '30/40/37')

df
#>     age   height   weight
#> 1 1/2/3 12/15/18 30/40/37
```

You could do

```
as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(x, '/')))))
#>   age height weight
#> 1   1     12     30
#> 2   2     15     40
#> 3   3     18     37
```

The same code will also work if your data is a named vector (it's not clear from the question what format your data is in, but the above code should work in either case as long as your data is called `df`)

<sup>Created on 2022-04-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. I made a change in my question. I really appreciate it if you answer that question too.